# Github pages só exibe conteúdo README.md

Tags: css, html5, git, repository

Bom dia, galera!
Estou tendo uma dificuldade que não consigo entender o porquê dela está acontecendo.
Tenho um repositório git contendo arquivos para exibição de uma página simples HTML e Css, contudo o meu github pages não está exibindo a página, apenas é mostrado o conteúdo do meu README.md.
Como faço para o conteúdo HTML e css serem exibidos, e não o arquivo README.md?

Comment: Segue as orientações do link que não tem erro: https://pages.github.com

Comment: Olá, @LeAndrade! Vou seguir a sus recomendação, e obrigado por ajudar.

Comment: Hum, fiz todos os passos do site do tutorial, mesmo assim só o conteúdo README.md continua aparecendo. https://trigueiros.github.io/

Comment: Você acabou não seguindo os passos do site, pois o passo onde fala para criar um arquivo `index.html` na raiz do projeto não foi realizada. Vendo o [seu repositório](https://github.com/Trigueiros/Trigueiros.github.io) parece que você precisa renomear o seu arquivo `ex_001_inicio.html` para `index.html`.

Comment: Pronto, @LeAndrade, o site já foi carregado, segui a dica de mudar o nome do arquivo HTML. Mas só tem mais um pequeno problema, o site não carregou as imagens. Será que devo comitar as imagens for da pasta img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa dos arquivos index.html, ou main.html na pasta raiz do seu projeto. No próprio Github pages tem esses orientações, é bem simples solucionar isso, pode demorar alguns minutos até sua pagina ser carregada também, espero ter ajudado.

[image: index.html na pasta raiz]
[image: index.html na pasta raiz]

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Olá, Igor! Segui as suas dicas e a de outro colega quanto ao arquivo index.html na raiz do meu projeto, e sim, resolveu o problema. Agora a página já está carregando com os estilos e imagens.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo mano. Boa sorte ai ...